# Expect script to login(ssh) and run command, password depends on environment

Tags: ssh, foreach, switch-statement, expect

I have searched the forums for some ideas and have gotten to a certain place where my script runs, with some issues at times.  I am trying to account for a handful of things.  Basically I am attempting to run a script with a server name and file, which will get pushed to the server.  After getting it there i need to move it to the proper place and then change permisssions on it.  Here is what i have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 5
set HOST [exec cat serverlist.txt]
set FILE [lindex $argv 0]
set LOC1 "/tmp/"
set LOC2 "/etc/sudoers.d/"
set USERS "testuser"
set PASSWORD "testpass"
foreach HOSTS $HOST {
spawn rsync $FILE $USERS@$HOSTS:$LOC1
expect {
    "*fingerprint*" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*assword*" {
        send "$PASSWORD\r"
        exp_continue
    }
}
spawn ssh $USERS@$HOSTS
expect {
    "*assword" {
        send "$PASSWORD\r"
    }
}
expect {
    "> " {
        send "sudo mv $LOC1$FILE $LOC2\r"
    }
}
expect {
    "*assword*" {
        send "$PASSWORD\r"
    }
}
expect {
    "> " {
        send "sudo chown root.root $LOC2${FILE}\r"
    }
}
expect {
    "> " {
        send "sudo chmod 440 $LOC2${FILE}\r"
    }
}
expect {
    "> " {
        send "visudo -c\r"
    }
}
}
expect eof
```

We have multiple environments and you have to use a different password with each of them.  If there is a way to escape illegal characters within the password that would be nice to incorporate also.  I have some instances where the script doesn't run properly even though I have the proper wildcards in there.  The way I know this is that I run "expect -df" in front of the command and can see the output.  Any assistance i can get on if i did this properly or if I can do it better?

I have attempted to simplify the code so that it can be easily reproduced.  I took out the "Environment piece" which basically set the user based on environment.(DEV,QA,PD, etc..)  What this does is copies over a sudoers file to /tmp/ and then moves it to /etc/sudoers.d/, changes permissions and then runs a check "visudo -c".  I would love to make this modular so that it can be used for more than just one thing.

example:  ./example.exp -l (user) -h (server or a file with servers) -f (file)

Something to that affect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i cannot run your script. do you have a [repro]?

Comment: and Expect uses Tcl. you can refer to Tcl's [doc](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/).

Comment: I have modified the script to hopefully allow it to be ran and tested by others.

Comment: what's your question?